# Why my output keeps being shown as NULL?

Tags: java, textfield

Why can't I calculate and set my output to the `textfield` created? I'm a beginner on this so please explain clearly if you could. I would like to set the output calculated by double a, b and c to be display inside the `textfield` but I just have no idea what's wrong with my codes.

Thanks! All help appreciated.

```
public class calcSalary extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
Double salary;
    String salary1 = String.valueOf(salary);

    //DecimalFormat currency = new DecimalFormat("0.00");        

Panel p1 = new Panel(new FlowLayout());

    JTextArea t1 = new JTextArea(salary1);        

//Label l1 = new Label("Calculate Staff Salary");
Label l2 = new Label("Hour(s)");
Label l3 = new Label("Day(s)");
Label l4 = new Label("Rate");
Label l5 = new Label("Salary");

Button b1 = new Button("Calculate");
Button b2 = new Button("Back");

Choice c1 = new Choice();
Choice c2 = new Choice();
Choice c3 = new Choice();


public calcSalary()
{
        setLayout(new GridLayout(5,3));

    c1.add("1");//set hours
    c1.add("2");
    c1.add("3");
    c1.add("4");
    c1.add("5");
    c1.add("6");
    c1.add("7");
    c1.add("8");
    c1.add("9");
    c1.add("10");

    c2.add("1");//set days
    c2.add("2");
    c2.add("3");
    c2.add("4");
    c2.add("5");
    c2.add("6");
    c2.add("7");
    c2.add("8");
    c2.add("9");
    c2.add("10");
    c2.add("11");
    c2.add("12");
    c2.add("13");
    c2.add("14");
    c2.add("15");
    c2.add("16");
    c2.add("17");
    c2.add("18");
    c2.add("19");
    c2.add("20");
    c2.add("21");
    c2.add("22");
    c2.add("23");
    c2.add("24");
    c2.add("25");
    c2.add("26");
    c2.add("27");
    c2.add("28");
    c2.add("29");
    c2.add("30");
    c2.add("31");

    c3.add("10");//set rates
    c3.add("15");
    c3.add("20");

    //add(l1);
    add(l2);
    add(c1);
    add(l3);
    add(c2);
    add(l4);
    add(c3);
    add(l5);
            add(t1);
            (t1).setEditable(false);
            add(b1);
    add(b2);

    b1.addActionListener(this);
    b2.addActionListener(this);

}

    /*public boolean check1(String id)
{
    if(id.equals(staffid))
    return true;
    else
    return false;
}*/


/*public void calc()
{
    Double salary;

    int a = c1.getSelectedIndex(); //c1 is the hours
    int b = c2.getSelectedIndex(); //c2 is the days
    double c = c3.getSelectedIndex(); //c3 is the rate

    salary = a * b * c;

}*/


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource() == b1)
    {     
                double a = Double.valueOf((String)c1.getSelectedItem());
                //int a = c1.getSelectedIndex(); //c1 is the hours
                double b = Double.valueOf((String)c2.getSelectedItem());
                //int b = c2.getSelectedIndex(); //c2 is the days
                double c = Double.valueOf((String)c3.getSelectedItem());
                //double c = c3.getSelectedIndex(); //c3 is the rate

                salary = a * b * c;
        //TO DO.....
                t1.setText(salary1);
    }

    if(e.getSource() == b2) 
    {
        JFrame frame = new admin();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        setVisible(false);
    }   
}
}   enter code here
```

Comment: I guess your issue is fixed, but please change your variable naming system. This is what is taught in first month of programming in university, classes, online courses. You, yourself will have problems later understanding what is exactly going on with your code. Follow the naming standards laid down by some awesome guys who went through a lot of trouble creating those standards in first place.

Comment: thanks for giving me the advice. Indeed, I'm new to this. :D

Answer (score 5):

Probably because of this:

```
 salary = a * b * c;
 //TO DO.....
 t1.setText(salary1);
```

You set different variable that you've computed.

Comment: but as i read from the Internet, TextArea or TextField only support String type and since I've declared the salary as double and afterwards I've changed it to salary1 which is in String, wouldn't it be an error if I use t1.setText(salary);?

    Double salary;
    String salary1 = String.valueOf(salary);

Comment: Steven, String is immutable. You have to create new one every time your `double` changes.

Comment: Hi, what does that mean? could you give me an example based on my code? thanks :)

Comment: It means this code:
`String salary1 = String.valueOf(salary);`
should be placed here before `t1.setText(salary1);`
instead of the beggining.

Comment: wow~that works!! thanks buddy! I now have an idea what's going on. :v